# Convert form data to a JS object with jQuery, including grouped values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I want to serialize my form data into a JSON object like it's described in the following thread: [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)
However besides of single fields which go as they appear in the form I have fields which I want to group into separate objects. For example, I have 2 fields - `startDate` and `endDate`. And in JSON object I want to achieve the following structure:

```
"dates" : {
     "startDate" : "03/19/2014",
     "endDate" : "03/27/2014"
},
```

So, I want to get the values for `firstDate` and `endDate`, combine them in an object `dates` and add to the object which contains the values for separate fields.

Can anybody give me a hint on how can this be achieved? Is there a way to define a some kind of JSON "template" and replace the values of properties with the values from the form?

And a more deep example which I'll need to support:

```
"demographic" : {
  "declaredGender" : "any",
      "estimatedGender" : "female",
      "estimatedGenderConfidence" : 50,
      "declaredYearOfBirth" : {
          "from" : "1960",
          "to" : "1990"
      },
      "estimatedYearOfBirth" : {
          "from" : "1980",
          "to" : "1990"
      },
      "estimatedYearOfBirthConfidence" : 50
},
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(options) {

    var data = $(this).serializeArray(),
        obj = {};

    $.each(data, function(i, el) {
        var key = el.name;
        if (el.name in options) {
            obj[options[key]] = obj[options[key]] || {};
            obj[options[key]][key] = el.value;
        }
        else {
            obj[key] = el.value;
        }
    });

    return obj;
};
```

You can use it this way:

```
var data = $('form').serializeObject({startDate: 'dates', endDate: 'dates'});
```

So you say in configuration that you want `startDate` field to go into `dates` group and so on. You also can define multiple groups, for example:

```
$('form').serializeObject({
    startDate: 'dates',
    endDate: 'dates',
    firstName: 'user',
    lastName: 'user'
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/UwFTr/1/

---

### UPD

For nested groups plugin can look like this:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(options) {

    function namespace(obj, keys, name, value) {
        keys = keys.split('.');
        var o = obj;
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            o[keys[i]] = o[keys[i]] || {};
            o = o[keys[i]];
        }
        o[name] = value;
        return obj;
    }

    var elements = $.makeArray($.prop(this[0], "elements")),
        obj = {};

    $.each(elements, function(i, el) {
        if (!el.name || $(el).is(":disabled")) return;

        var group = $(el).attr('group');

        if (!group) {
            obj[el.name] = $(el).val();
        }
        else {
            obj = namespace(obj, group, el.name, $(el).val());
        }
    });

    return obj;
};
```

Use it in HTML:

```
<input type="date" name="startDate" group="event.dates" value="2014-03-26">
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/UwFTr/2/

Comment: Thanks, this works great for 2 levels, but there are cases with deeper structures. I've updated my question with such an example. This function won't work for that.

Comment: Any solution for such a scenario?

Answer (score -1):

You could group the inputs using divs or other elements and use an attribute such as id or a data- prefixed html5 attribute for the json key.  In the below example I have used `$.attr()` to pluck id's for the groups, and name for the individual inputs.

http://jsfiddle.net/A9XvJ/